# Execute random css alterations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, random

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() > 200) {
    $('#box').css({height:'100px', background-color:'green', overflow:'visible', width:'550px', margin:'0 auto'
  });

  $('#box2').css({position:'fixed',left:'400px',height:'200px',background: '#CF0'});
}
```

I am new to javascript, this might as well be a quick question...

What I have here is modifying the css styles of a div (#box) depending on the location of the page you are on (> 200 in this case).

What I am trying to achieve is to add multiple css alterations to #box and to execute a random one each time. For example each time you scroll pass 200 from the very top, the div appears either in height:'100px' with green background, height:'200px' with blue background, OR height:'300px' with red background. Hope this make sense....

Comment: The code you posted seems to be doing that. What's the problem you're having?

Comment: Yeah it works, but I want to add random css multiple alterations to one of the divs, and I have trouble looking for a solution to that, thank you

Comment: You have to be more specific... What do you want to be random? Did you try anything? Do you know how to generate a random number with js?

Comment: Sorry if the question was vague. So what I want is to execute either one of these 3 different css variables. Not a random number.

1. 100px in green background
2. 200px in yellow background
3. 300px in red background

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this (adjust your `scrollTop` value and `css style`)

**JS:**

```
var classes = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 20) {
        var cls = classes[Math.floor( Math.random() * classes.length )];
        $('#box').toggleClass(cls);
    }
 });
```

**CSS:**

```
.a {
    background:red;
    height:100px;
}
.b {
    background:green;
    height:200px;
}
.c {
    background:blue;
    height:300px;
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7kbDm/)

**Update :** toggles only once every `scrolldowm`

```
$(function(){
    var classes = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    function down()
    {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > 20 ) {
            var cls = classes[Math.floor( Math.random() * classes.length )];
            $('#box').toggleClass(cls);
            $(window).off('scroll.down');
        }
    }

    $(window).on('scroll.down', down).on('scroll.up', function(){
        if ($(window).scrollTop() < 20 ) {
            $(window).on('scroll.down', down);
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/7kbDm/2/)

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be working...however it's constantly changing the class as you scroll. I meant to it stay at a particular class of the three.

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be working...however it's constantly changing the class as you scroll. I meant for it to stay at a particular class of the three. @RCV